# How to build web flow in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web

I am administering online surveys for discounts. I am using a web based tool similar to survey monkey.

I have a python script that is reads in a json file of survey results. From here based on a randomizer issues a win or lose, if you win you get the discount, if lose you get nothing.

I am wanting to have a designer create a beautiful webpage and I want to launch the website if you win in the same browser window that the survey is being taken in.

How would I do this?

The flow of the website is:

website URL for the survey displayed -> take survey and hit submit -> python script parses and selects winner/loser -> if winner, display website of winner page -> reset page back to URL of survey

edit:
open to all frameworks/tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways that you can implement these things. 
One way that you can do today would be to use a React + Flask stack

You can use [react](https://github.com/facebook/react) to implement your front-end and use Python's [Flask](https://github.com/pallets/flask) to do all your Python logic.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I dont know any JS for the react piece is there anything in pure python? I dont know if this will help but another developer will be developing the landing page so I only want to create functionality that will fire once certain buttons are picked.

Comment: You can use Django. There you could implement both the Flask and the React part if you wanted.